# Use Valence to Get User Data

Tags: api, rest, desire2learn

According to the documentation I can get user data by calling:

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/
```

And I can use the d2lId, username or bookmark param.
I have tried this simply by appending the username string to the uri but it didn't work. Does the uri require a parameter name in order to understand what param I'm submitting to the query? i.e. ?username="someUsername"

Note that I have been able to return user specific data by simply appending the d2lId to the uri so API access is a non-issue. Also LE version is not an issue - I'm using > 9.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating two different calls, and this is the source of the confusion. The [call to the `users/` route](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-users-) mentioned in your question is one to fetch back data for all users (in data pages):

- `orgDefinedId` -- provide an org-defined identifier, and seek for matches against that
- `userName` -- provide a user name, and seek for matches against that
- `bookmark` -- provide the bookmark needed to fetch the next data page

So in your example, the API call could look like this:

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/?userName=Bob%20Roberts
```

Notice that there's also a route to [fetch the user data for a particular user](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-users-%28D2LID-userId%29) identified by LMS UserId value:

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/123456
```

But these are actually two different REST routes. You can't use the LMS UserId as a filter for the `users/` route...